# Using History.js - I'm confused

Tags: javascript, jquery, history.js

I'm implementing ajax navigation and I'd like to utilize the html5 history API, so I stumled upon History.js.

I'm not exactly sure how to go about using it and the documentation for it is not very good, nore are the examples.

I tried to mess with it...

```js
$("a[href]:not(.no-ajax-navigate)").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var path = $(this).attr('data-path');//this is "path/to/page" (clean url's)
    //so I got the path.. now what? pushState?
});
```

I'm clueless as to what to do now.. thanks in advance!

### update 1

I looked at the [source code that]@OneTrickPony commented](http://html5.gingerhost.com/new-york) that @OneTrickPony commented and I got it working. But it seems fire fire a popstate event on page load. Is this supposed to happen? My page basically fade in/out which is kinda annoying when you initially load (refresh) the browser.

Comment: I don't know how one uses History.js while managing to *not* be confused :-)

Comment: [Here](http://html5.gingerhost.com/)'s a very good example of history API usage

Comment: @OneTrickPony that's a good site, but the History.js library abstracts the native APIs (to smooth over various weirdnesses), and adds some complications.

Comment: @OneTrickPony nice, I'm reading through the source code now :P

Comment: I got it working but I have an other problem. I edited my post to reflect the new problem :P

Answer (score 1):

It's important to note you can use HTML5 history without using History.js (see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)).

History.js does give you some nice features like being able to store additional data in the history call stack.  The following will set your URL path without a refresh.

```
$("a[href]:not(.no-ajax-navigate)").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var path = $(this).attr('data-path');//this is "path/to/page" (clean url's)

  // Set the URL using History.js (note the capital H)
  var History = window.History;
  History.pushState(null, null, path);
});
```

You can use the first two arguments in pushState to store additional data (see [here](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/#functions) for more details).

To go back use: `History.back();`

To catch the URL change event you can use:

```
History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function(){
  var History = window.History;
  var State = History.getState();
  // Do something here with State
});
```